# Error evaluating embedded expressions: How to get just the date part from the datetime in telerik report

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, telerik, telerik-reporting

I want to get the printing date in my telerik report so i bind like this :

```
Printing date{Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Now())}
```

but i face run time error like this :

```
Error evaluating embedded expressions: Unexpected token inside an expression at index 23
```

How to get just the date part from the datetime in my report ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the expression as follows:

= "Printing Date "+ Now().ToString("MMdd/yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

Replying to an old question, but here it is anyway. You needed to [escape the embedded curly braces](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/expressions-embedded)

```
Printing date{Format("{{0:MM/dd/yyyy}}", Now())}
```